# Calculate the difference between cell j and cell j+1 then j+1 and j+2, j+2 and j+3...of a dataframe and keep the digger result (closed))

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python programming and i run into this problem.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    ID   0      1      2      3    4    5    6    7    8   9    10   11    12   13
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  A984 2020-  NaT    NaT    NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT
        01-13  

1  B879 2020-  NaT    NaT    NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT
        02-24


2  C456 2020-  2020-  2020-  NaT   NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT
        09-14  10-16  10-18
        

3  D342 2020-   NaT   NaT    NaT   NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT
        03-13


4  Y523 2020-  2020-  2020-  2020-  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT
        03-14  05-16  09-18  09-23


5  H669 2020-  2020-  2020-  2020-  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT
        03-14  05-16  05-20  09-20
```

And I want to find the max difference between those dates for every id, and then put it in a new column of my dataframe.

My results should look like:

```
    ID   0      1      2      3    4    5    6    7    8   9    10   11    12   13   Max Days
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0  A984 2020-  NaT    NaT    NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT      NaT
        01-13  

1  B879 2020-  NaT    NaT    NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT      NaT
        02-24


2  C456 2020-  2020-  2020-  NaT   NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT     32
        09-14  10-16  10-18
        

3  D342 2020-   NaT   NaT    NaT   NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT     NaT
        03-13


4  Y523 2020-  2020-  2020-  2020-  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT    125
        03-14  05-16  09-18  09-23


5  H669 2020-  2020-  2020-  2020-  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT  NaT    123
        03-14  05-16  05-20  09-20
```

I have tried:

```
df['Max Days'] = ""

for inDex in range(df.shape[0]):
   for index in range(df.shape[1]):
       if df[index+1].empty != True: 
           dif = df[index+1].sub(df[index],axis=0)
           if df['Max Days'][index] < dif:
               df['Max Days'][index] == dif
           else:
               df['Max Days'][index] == pd.NaT
       else: continue;
```

And i am getting the error: "ValueError: The truth value is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Any help would be much appreciated.

**New attempt:**

```
df["Max Days"] = pd.to_timedelta(0, unit='D')

for i in df.index :
    for j in df.columns:
            min_date=df[j][i]
            max_date=df[j+1][i]
            if max_date == pd.to_timedelta(0, unit='D'):
                break;
            else:
                diff = max_date - min_date
                df["Max Days"][i] = max(diff,df["Max Days"][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that all dates stored in your DataFrame are of `datetime` type and then try this:

```
def max_date_diff(dates):
    min_date = min(dates)
    max_date = max(dates)
    return max_date - min_date

df["Max Days"] = df.apply(max_date_diff, axis=1) #passes a Series object, row-wise
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast answer, but that's not exactly what I want. If I've understood this right, the above code finds the max and min of the dates in every row and then returns the difference. What I want is to find the difference between 2020- 03-14 and 2020- 05-16, which is 63 days and then find the difference between 2020- 05-16 and 2020- 09-18 , which is 125 days and because 125 > 63 keep the 125 in the Max Days column. @Trustworthy

Comment: @Timothee No worries! This code will add an extra column to your DataFrame called "Max Days" which will have the max difference of dates for every row. The df.apply(function, axis=1) applies the function row wise... which sounds like what you're looking for? There is no need to find all permutations of diff_days (e.g. 125, 63) and calculate which one is highest (63), this way is much faster.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! I made a mistake and didn't explain correctly what my results should be. I think I have to edit the question. What I wanted was to find and keep the maximum days between: ( let's say for row 4, id:Y523) 2020- 03-14 and 2020-05-16 and then 2020-05-16 and 2020-09-18 and so on... So between all those periods I want to keep the maximum. I think I made it and I am leaving my code in the question above. Any comments would be much appreciated. Have a nice day!@Trustworthy